# iOS - removing all references/connectios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get the same problem as [iOS - removing reference of a property I had deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654880/ios-removing-reference-of-a-property-i-had-deleted)

I created a view with two inputs and a own controller "HomeController".
I connected the inputs with the controller with names "inputLogin" and "inputPassword".

Then it worked a few times unless I decided to rename my Controller to ParametersController.

I tried a lot of things, such as :
- Renaming the classes (.h/.m) and the custom class name in the storyboard.
- Delete the whole things (classes, views) and recreated a new view with nothing inside and no custom class.

But still, I get the error `<UIViewController 0xXXXXXXX> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputLogin`.

I check all of the "connections", there is no references to inputLogin.

If you have any suggestion.

Thanks.

Added: In fact, it seems like my running project isn't the current version. In my storyboard, I removed some views, but these are still there when I run my project :(

Comment: Seems odd but have you tried quitting an re-opening Xcode? Restarting your Mac? If you're running in Simulator try resetting its contents.

Comment: Yeah, it seems related to the Simulator. I deleted the app inside and resetting contents and now that's work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning your project (Product > Clean). It is quite safe, Xcode precompile lots of things to speedup build time. The downside (of precompiling) is that sometimes, some leftovers are not being updated.
Cleaning simply gives you a clean build and get rid of all leftovers.

Comment: - " I decided to rename my Controller to ParametersController." I suspect this might be the problem. Try creating a new ViewContoller and copy/paste from the old one to the new one. Xcode probably still holds a reference to the old name

Comment: I deleted all controllers to come back to a simple view with no custom class. But yeah Xcode seems to get a reference somewhere, I just don't know where.
In fact, like I added in my question, it seems that my project doesn't read my current version of my storyboard..

Comment: I've had this problems several times. In my case deleting the app from simulator (or the device) and running it again helped and everything was up to date.

Comment: Thanks hacker2007. I deleted my app in the simulator and resetting contents. And all worked fine :)

Comment: I usually back up versions of my apps by simply copy (from the finder, option+drag) the whole project folder (of the app) to a backup folder. In a case like this one, if the simulator was the faulty one, you can simply pull the latest backup without having to recreate anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you renamed the variables in .h or .m file you will need to reconnect those outlets to viewControllers UI and make sure to delete the old IBoutlet from UI viewController for those(fields or buttons)and this keyCodingcompliant error will be resolved

Comment: I'm sure I removed all references in the connections inspector. In fact, it seems that my current storyboard isn't "linked" with my project. I renamed some buttons, but when I run my project, I still get the "old" version.

Comment: Did you create a whole new storyboard.If yes than you have to change launch option to new storyboard target>general>deployment ifo

Comment: No, I created only one storyboard. I don't have another one (I checked the files).
If it can help, I tried to internationalize my project (so it created a second storyboard for "french"). But I deleted this version, in case of it was related to my problem.